# Unable to Switch to New Window Running Test with C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using C# and Selenium to try to automate testing of our web site. I have a link that when clicked opens up a new window. I'm trying to figure out how to switch to this new window to continue the testing.

I've tried the following line which I've found on many blogs, but Last is not showing up in Intellisense and has the red squiggly under it.

```
driverIE.SwitchTo().Window(driverIE.WindowHandles.Last());
```

I'm new to working with C# in Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if I'm not including something I should be. Here is the start of the test I'm trying to run.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        static IWebDriver driverIE;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
        {
            driverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Selenium");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestIEDriver()
        {
            driverIE.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/site/");
            driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserId")).SendKeys("username");
            driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).SendKeys("password");
            driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

            //Open Quote
            driverIE.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            driverIE.FindElement(By.LinkText("Personal Auto")).Click();

            //Switch to Quote Window
            driverIE.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowList = driverIE.WindowHandles;
            driverIE.SwitchTo().Window(driverIE.WindowHandles.Last());
            driverIE.FindElement(By.Id("txtAgencyCd")).SendKeys("Code");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this once you switch to your url

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); //you can change 10 seconds to whatever it suits you the best.
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("login")));
```

Comment: You can drop in whatever id you are waiting for. I used login for my window to wait until i get the login element

Comment: When I "click" the link in the first windows, it automatically launches a new window on top of the old one, so there are now 2 windows. I'm trying to figure out how to switch to the new window. The link that gets clicked uses javascript to open the new window.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.